# Does $R[x] \cong S[x]$ imply $R \cong S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

This is a very simple question but I believe it's nontrivial.

I would like to know if the following is true:

> If $R$ and $S$ are rings and $R[x]$ and $S[x]$ are isomorphic as rings, then $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic.

Thanks!

If there isn't a proof (or disproof) of the general result, I would be interested to know if there are particular cases when this claim is true.

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0483v2.pdf

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $R=\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{\big(xy - (1 - z^2)\big)}$, $S=\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{\big(x^2y - (1 - z^2)\big)}$. Then, $R$ is not isomorphic to $S$ but, $R[T]\cong S[T]$.

In many variables, this is called the Zariski problem or cancellation of indeterminates and is largely open. [Here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/Lip.text.pdf) is a discussion by Hochster (problem 3).

Comment: May I ask what the isomorphism $f\!:R[T]\!\rightarrow\!S[T]$ is, and how do we know that $R\!\ncong\!S$? I'm hoping for an elementary answer...

Comment: Additionally -- what is $T$? An arbitrary ring? A copy of Z ... ?

Comment: @AlexMeiburg : it denotes an intedeterminate ; $R[T]$ is the polynomial ring of 1 variable over $R$. Said differently, it is the [monoid algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) of $\Bbb N$ over $R$.

Answer (score 47):

I found the paper [*Isomorphic polynomial rings*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01304919) by Brewer and Rutter that discusses
related matters. They cite a forthcoming paper by Hochster
which proves there are non-isomorphic
commutative integral domains $R$ and $S$ with $R[x]\cong S[x]$.

**Added**

Hochster's paper is
M. Hochster, *Nonuniqueness of coefficient rings in a polynomial ring*,
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 34 (1972), 81-82, and is [freely available](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/home.html).

Answer (score 24):

There's been much work on this problem since the mentioned seminal work in the early seventies. Searching on the buzzword "stably equivalent" should help locate most of it. Below is a helpful introduction from Jon L Johnson: [Cancellation and Prime Spectra](http://books.google.com/books?id=m7MKj5tLAJwC&lpg=PA277&ots=Wc0BuJo04-&dq=brewer%20rutter%20hochster&pg=PA277#v=onepage&q=picard&f=false)
[image]
[image]

Comment: If we assume that $R$ and $S$ are subrings of $\Bbb R$ (or of $\Bbb C$), do you know if there is an example where $R[x] \cong S[x]$ but $R \not \cong S$?

Answer (score 20):

Along the lines of "particular cases where the claim is true," if $R$ and $S$ are fields, then they must be isomorphic since they are distinguishable as the units (excepting zero of course) of $R[x]$ and $S[x]$, respectively, and an isomorphism conserves units.

More generally if we only know that one of $R$ or $S$ is a field, the claim is still true.

Suppose $R$ is a field and $R[X] \cong S[Y]$, where $X,Y$ are distinct indeterminates for clarity, and $f:R[X] \rightarrow S[Y]$ is an isomorphism.  Since the nonzero elements of $f(R)$ are units in $S[Y]$, they must be degree zero, i.e. elements of $S$.  Also the inverse image of $S$ is a subring of Euclidean domain $R[X]$, so $S$ is an integral domain.

Knowing that $f(R) \subseteq S$, we need only show $f$ maps $R$ onto $S$.  Suppose $s \in S$.  Then there exists polynomial $p(X) \in R[X]$ s.t. $f(p(X)) = s$.  Let $p(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n \enspace r_i X^i$ where coefficients $r_i \in R$.

Now $f(X) = q(Y)$ for some polynomial $q(Y) \in S[Y]$, and degree of $q(Y)$ must be positive for $f(R[X]) = S[Y]$.  Apply $f$ to $p(X)$ and compare degrees:

$$s = \sum_{i=0}^n \enspace f(r_i) q(Y)^i$$

Since $S$ is an integral domain, the degrees of $q(Y)^i$ are positive for $i \gt 0$.  Thus the only nonzero coefficient of $p(X)$ is $r_0$, which shows $f(r_0) = s$.  Therefore $f$ maps $R$ onto $S$ and $R \cong S$.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the reasoning in your first paragraph : $(R[X])^{\times} = R^{\times} \cong S^{\times} = (S[X])^{\times}$ doesn't imply $R \cong S$ as fields. You can even see problem 10E in Halmos _Problems for Mathematicians, Young and Old_.

Comment: @Watson: Here we have an isomorphism of rings $R[X]$ and $S[Y]$ and subrings $R,S$ resp. which both happen to be fields.  A degree argument is meant to show that the image of $R$ is $S$ under the isomorphism, and therefore that these are isomorphic as rings.  I'll look for the Halmos exercise, but I suspect the point there is one knows only a isomorphism of (multiplicative) groups.