# Is it possible to have $F \not \cong F(X) \cong F(X,Y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples, extension-field

> Is there a field $F$ such that $F \not \cong F(X)$ as fields but $F(X) \cong F(X,Y)$ ?

---

An example might not be obvious to find, since it would give an exemple of non-isomorphic fields $K \not\cong L$ such that $K(t) \cong L(t)$ (let $K=F, L=F(X)$). Such an example is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96777).

Notice that my question is different from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000333) one (and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258647) one), since there I was asking for $ F(X) \not \cong F \cong F(X,Y) $.
Possibly related: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448250).

By the way, a similar question for polynomial rings can be asked: is there a unital commutative ring $R$ such that $R \not \cong R[X] \cong R[X,Y]$ (as rings)? I don't have an example either for this one.

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261423