# Is $k(x)[y]$ isomorphic to $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't think so but could not prove or disprove.

Since I dont believe it.

---

I tried to use

1. We can understand that $k(x)\not\cong k[x,x^{-1}]$
   one of them is field but other is not.

However $S[x]\cong T[x] \not\Rightarrow S\cong T$ since, in general see: [Does $R[x] \cong S[x]$ imply $R \cong S$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/does-rx-cong-sx-imply-r-cong-s)

---

2. Like $k[x][y]=k[y][x]$ I try to change $k(x)[y]=(k[y])(x)$ but again one of them is field but other is not.

---

3. I try to think about $R[x]$ and formal polynomial series $R[[x]]$ and thought that if a polynomail in $R[[x]]$ is not invertible then it cannot be invertible in $R[x]$ but every invertible element in formal series are with nonzero constant if we have purely x polynomial it can be inverted in in subring $R[x]$ considering canonical injection into $R[[x]]$

---

4. Try to find some examples as: $x+1$ is invertible in $k(x)[y]$ since $1/(x+1)$ in here but $x+1$ is not invertible in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ since if it was invertible then
   $$1=(x+1)\left(\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}a_i(y)x^n\right)$$
   where $a_i(y)\in k[y]$ and finitely many $a_i(y)$ are nonzero. We can see that $x+1$ is non invertible in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ but I cannot be sure about $x+1$ should be mapped to $x+1$.

**I thought that if** there was a isomorphism $\phi :k(x)[y]\to k[x,x^{-1},y]$ then $\phi(x+1)$ should be invertible in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ but we dont know where this $\phi$ map our $x+1$ to?

Edit:

Alex Wertheim's comment is vanished with some deleted answer so I am adding his good coment here (If he likes, please edit and delete your comment here)

Alex Wertheim : "It would probably be easier to note that $R/yR≅k[x,x^{-1}]$, and so $R$ contains a nonzero prime ideal which is not maximal, and hence cannot be a PID."

Comment: I think the easiest (maybe laziest) way to show this is by simply noting that $k(x)[y]$ is a PID while $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is not.

Comment: In the link, there is an argument of why, if $R$ is a field (but not necessarily $S$ as well), then $R[x] \cong S[x]$ only if $R \cong S$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I have noticed it now, then we can use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Douglas Molin suggested in the comments, because $k(x)$ is a field (even if $k$ is not algebraically closed), there is a well-known theorem that says $R[x]$ is a PID iff $R$ is a field, which means $k(x)[y]$ is a PID.

But $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is not a PID since $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is not a field (look at $x+1$).

Comment: Your justification for why $R := k[x, x^{-1}, y]$ is not a PID is not correct. The ideal generated by $x, y$ is all of $R$, since $x$ is a unit. It would probably be easier to note that $R/yR \cong k[x, x^{-1}]$, and so $R$ contains a nonzero prime ideal which is not maximal, and hence cannot be a PID.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** how you can complete your argument: $\phi(x)$ has to be an element which has no square root. In $k[x,x^{-1},y]$, if an element $\alpha$ has no square root, then it is not in $k$, so either $\alpha$ or $\alpha+1$ is not invertible (to see this, prove that $\alpha$ is invertible iff $x^k\cdot \alpha$ is invertible in $k[x,y]$ for some $k\in \mathbf Z$).

(Note that the other argument gives you a stronger theorem, as you don't need $k$ to be algebraically closed.)